# Can I write a DTO which extracts both query and params vars in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I'm making an api which looks like:

`http://example.com/story/:storyId/analytics?from={date}&to={date}`

The `storyId` is part of the path, but `from` and `to` are query parameters.

I've got a DTO, like this:

```js
class GetStoryAnalyticsDTO {
  storyId: string
  from: Date
  to: Date
}
```

(validators omitted for brevity)

And I'm using it like this in my controler:

```js
@Get()
getStoryAnalytics(@Query() query: GetStoryAnalyticsRequestDto): Promise<MyResponse> {...}
```

But, (obviously!), this only extracts the from and to parameters.

Is there any way to extract both from the query and the path to get all the vars in one dto?

If not, it's not a massive hassle - I can just add `@Param storyId: string` to the controller and it's all good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a custom decorator like `@QueryParam()` that pulls together `req.query` and `req.params`. It could look something like this:

```js
export const QueryParam = createParamDecorator((data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return { ...req.query, ...req.params };
});
```

And just make sure to add `validateCustomDecorators` on the `ValidationPipe` if you want it to auto validate for you. Otherwise, you're good to start using it.